# Can't figure out geolocation

Tags: jquery, geolocation

So I'm trying to use geolocation in Javascript for the first time. I basically copied over the code from another stack overflow jsfiddle example, that worked, but I'm getting some weird errors. For awhile I was getting a "maximum callstack size exceeded jquery" error (and like 20 calls to `getLocation()` ) in the JS console, and now I'm getting nothing back - except for the little target icon in the address bar with an X over it saying location permission denied (even after automatically allowing all location requests). That's on chrome. Tried safari, it gave an alert asking for permission but then nothing happened. Still no errors. Any suggestions?

```
    $(window).load(function() {
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        else {
            $('#test').write("Couldn't fetch location.");
        };
    };

    function showPosition(position) {
        $('#test').write("<h1>Latitude: \"" + position.coords.latitude + "\"</h1>");
        $('#test').write("<h1>Longitude: \"" + position.coords.longitude + "\"</h1>");
    };

    getLocation();
});,
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `write()` method in jQuery, and you have a comma at the end there.
Fix the syntax errors and it should work :

```
$(function() {
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        else {
            $('#test').html("Couldn't fetch location.");
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        $('#test').html("<h1>Latitude: \"" + position.coords.latitude + "\"</h1>");
        $('#test').append("<h1>Longitude: \"" + position.coords.longitude + "\"</h1>");
    }

    getLocation();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uHK6f/)

Comment: Thanks! The comma was a typo in pasting the code on here, but obviously the problem was with the 'write' command. Still not getting any results in Chrome, though, although it's working in Safari and Firefox - any ideas?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100353 looks like it's a chrome  bug for locally hosted files.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

var x=document.getElementById("test");

function getLocation()
{
if( navigator.geolocation{navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( showPosition);
}
else { x.innerHTML = "Geolocation  is not supported by this browser.";
}}function showPosition(position){x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + <br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; }

</script>
```